# Does $3\leq\omega(G)\leq k$ imply $\chi(G)\leq k$ for $n\geq 3$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I asked weaker version of this question in [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/283242/90655).

Let $G$ be a simple graph with $n$ vertices. Let $\omega(G)$ and $\chi(G)$ denotes the clique number and chromatic number of $G$ respectively. Then

> Does $3\leq\omega(G)\leq k$ imply $\chi(G)\leq k$ for $n\geq 3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There are triangle free graphs $G$ of [arbitrarily high chromatic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girth_(graph_theory)#Girth_and_graph_coloring). Add one edge to $G$ to form a triangle. Then $\omega(G)=3$ but $\chi(G)$ is as large as before.

See for example the [Grötsch graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6tzsch_graph) with $\chi(G)=4$, but we can add a triangle to make $\omega(G)=3$:

[image]